# Tag badge descriptions are ambiguous

Tags: feature-request

The gold tag badge description reads

> Earned at least 1000 **total score** for at least 200 answers in the `[sometag]` tag.

It is not clear if *score* means reputation or (up)votes.

Applies to bronze and silver badge as well.

*Edit*:
New wording should explicitly mention votes, since the term "score" is only seldomly used on SO, while "votes" and "reputation" are well known. As has been pointed out in the comments, the term "score" even has been inconsistently used in the glossary for the definition of "reputation".

Proposed new wording:

> Earned at least 1000 **net votes** for at least 200 answers in the `[sometag]` tag.

Or with clarification:

> Earned at least 1000 **net votes (upvotes minus downvotes)** for at least 200 answers in the `[sometag]` tag.

Comment: There does need to be a definition of score somewhere on the page. Or change to "net upvotes"

Comment: We have a [glossary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/152859).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I usually try to follow the rule that if the user has to read the manual then you have failed

Comment: @RichardTingle might be, but starting to explain every term in every badge description will lead to huge walls of text.  I prefer to keep in compact and simple, and those who want the full details can research further using the glossary or meta search. On this specific case, "score" is clear enough.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes. And in there, first reputation is defined as "total score achieved by a user", and later score is defined as the net votes on an answer. Users are likely to have read the definition of reputation and assuming that "score equals reputation".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd True, advanced things can be manual based, but a change from "score" to "net votes" uses words which have no ambiguity. Score is (in normal life) very often 10 times the number of actual points (for reasons that are beyond me) so interpreting it as reputation is not suprising

Comment: @RichardTingle as I poitned out, "score" is actually used for the definition of reputation in said glossary.

Comment: Indeed, from the glossary; "A user's "reputation" is the total score achieved by a user"

Comment: @Richard and Arne - I agree the current definition of reputation in the glossary is confusing, blame [Robert for this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/40354/84) - nobody is perfect. :) {going to try and think of a better definition}

Comment: @ArneMertz see the glossary now. No more confusing "score" in the definition of reputation. :)

Comment: @interjay right. ignore this question - or close it ;-) (can't delete)

Answer (score 4):

I disagree. When an answer has 3 upvotes and 1 downvote, then its **score** is 2, but its **upvotes count** is 3, and the badge description is talking about the score.

Comment: You have a point. It should not be *total upvotes* then, but still I don't think "score" is a good choice, since the term is only seldomly used on SO, while "votes" and "reputation" are well known.

Comment: Then what other new wording do you propose? Perhaps 'answer score' is clearer.

Comment: I think "total votes" would do, since it is known that up- and downvotes cancel each other.

Comment: No, because if there're 3 upvotes and 1 downvote, then 'total votes' would be 4

Comment: The word we're looking for is "net" votes

Comment: @RichardTingle great, edited my proposal.